# Does sizeof work at compile time?

Tags: c, sizeof

I ran this sample program.

```
const int x = 5;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x[x];

    int y = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);

    return 0;
}
```

The Value of y is 5.

But how is this possible? Because when I debugged, the value of x was 5, so the size of x is 4 and size of int is 4. And value of y should have been different .

What am I missing?

Comment: If and only if for variable-length array, `sizeof` acts in runtime.

Comment: You just doing yourself and the debugger a pain by using the same name `x` for your `const`-qualified variable of type `int` and for the array. Don't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof(x)` refers to the array which has `5` elements of type `int`. Hence the output.

The code would be a lot easier to understand if you didn't overload the name `x`.

Technically what you have here is a variable length array, a VLA. This is because C `const` actually means read-only and has to be evaluated at run time. Hence `sizeof`, in this case, is evaluated at runtime.

If you had used a literal to size your array instead, i.e. `int x[5];` then `sizeof` would have been evaluated at compile time.

If the code had been compiled as C++ then the const would be a true const, and so available for evaluation at compile time.

Comment: David, So if it has been in C++, the out put have been y=(5/4); (in 32-bit machine). Why such a difference in interpretation of const keyword?

Comment: no, the output would still be 5. sizeof counts bytes, not elements. Differences in const are historical in nature.

Answer (score 4):

You have variable hiding going on here. Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
const int x = 5;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x2[x];

    int y = sizeof(x2) / sizeof(int);

    return 0;
}
```

Then it's clearer: `sizeof(x)==4`, `x==5`, `sizeof(x2)==20`.

Answer (score 0):

x is of type int[5]. Therefore, the size is 5*sizeof(int).  sizeof is an operator, not a function or a macro.

This is why some people get annoyed when people claim that C arrays are just pointers, but unfortunately you can't pass an array. You can only pass a pointer to it's first element, and you loose this information.

Answer (score -2):

Since int x is `const`, this is a fixed size array. Sizeof is calculated at compilation time.

`x` has five elements, as the definition clearly shows. It's size is 5 * sizeof(int).

This is GCC, I use printf to print out the value of y:

```
subl    $48, %esp
movl    $5, 4(%esp)`
```

Both the allocated space and the value of y is compiled as constants.

Also, from the standard:

```
If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has
a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type [...]
```

Comment: Actually it being const means read-only, not constant (consider what would happen if it would be external). That's one of the reasons it only works in C99.

Comment: @David: His first paragraph is correct. All arrays in C have a fixed size.

Comment: @arafangion no, this is a VLA since const  cannot be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @David: Yet that particular instance can't change it's size, so the size is fixed at that point (at least, for that stack frame)?  In C99 with VLA's, I can initialize an array to whatever size i like - doesn't need to be a constant, but once I define that array, it's fixed to that size? I mean that you can't resize it later (eg, with realloc)

Comment: @David: that `const int x` is an integer constant expression.

Comment: const int x = 5 does not make x a constant expression.

Comment: @arafangion once the VLA is allocated then its size is fixed of course! The point is when this happens, compile time or run time.

Comment: @David: Ah, I think I mixed up my terminology, how should I point out that the array has a fixed size? (I spend most of my time in non-C languages)